# how to display the maximum value in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main()
{
   int numbers[30];
   int i;

   // making array of 30 random numbers under 100
   for(i=0;i<30;i++)
   {
       numbers[i] = rand() % 100; 
   }

   // finding the greatest number in the array
   int greatest = 0;
   srand(1);
   for(i=0;i<30;i++)
   {
        if ( numbers[i] > greatest) 
            greatest = numbers[i];
   }
```

How do I then tell the program to display the max value of the array??
Thank you

Comment: display..? cout >> greatest maybe?

Comment: Are you asking how to display things to a console? In a gui? Print to a file and then display it? Holographically project it into a room?

Comment: @Falmarri: would be great having an hologram in front of you! ;)

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 6):

To display it in the basic console output:

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout << "Max value is: " << greatest << "\n";
```

Comment: and return 0 and closing the braces of main()..I guess he has pasted that code in a hurry : D

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << greatest << '\n';
```

On a sidenote, you might want to call `srand()` before your call `rand()` (and might want to supply a more meaningful parameter).

Comment: Why is he using rand() at all?

Comment: @fahad: Well, the function is there for generating (pseudo-)random numbers, so I suppose that's what mike wants to do.

Comment: If he wants to find the largest number than why doesn't he compare greatest to each and every number and insert the greater number in greatest(if the number is greater)?Wont that be a better way?

Comment: @fahad: he does so, in the second loop. (The first is just to populate the array.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing this for home work I would suggest using std::max_element (available in `<algorithm>`).

```
std::cout << "Max Value: " << *(std::max_element(number, numbers+30)) << std::endl;
```

Otherwise, in your program all thats left to do is to print the value. You could use std::cout (available in `<iostream>`). After you've computed the great in the for loop.

```
// Dump the value greatest to standard output
std::cout << "Max value: " << greatest << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is better than his algorithm, but he asked how to print it.

Comment: Since the question looks like homework, I don't really see how dumping a line of intermediate level C++ (I don't consider iterators to be "beginner's stuff") will help the OP.

Comment: If my answer does not directly help the question poster, hopefully it will be useful to another reader someday. :)

Comment: If you're going to use `std::cout` instead of `cout`, then you should add `std::` to your `endl` s too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're referring to?

`printf("%d", greatest);`

Make sure to include "cstdio".

Comment: It's <cstdio> in C++, not <stdio.h>. And, (but that is subjective of course) for a beginner, I think std::cout is slightly easier to use.

Comment: Didn't know about the cstdio part, I changed it; thanks.
C++ is a superset of C though, right? So this is valid C++.
When I was learning C++, I thought cout and cin were horrendous in terms of the fact that they overload operators that weren't meant to be overloaded, and the confused me completely as a beginner. Printf()'s format specifications aren't intuitive, but at least they use more readable syntax... but, as you said, this is subjective. :)

Comment: @Lambert - valid yes, recommended no.  Use `iostream` in C++, not the C runtime library.

Comment: @Steve - Ok, thanks for pointing it out. I'm new to the site, so I didn't know that; I'll try to remember that. :)

Comment: It takes a bit of getting used to style-wise, but the CRT can be nicely emulated by Standard Library means.  For a C tagged question your answer is perfect, of course (apart from the header file name).

Comment: `weren't meant to be overloaded` Why do you think those operators aren't meant to be overloaded?

Comment: I guess here's some clarification: They were meant to be overloaded, but in the right context (such as in a BigInteger class). Changing a bitwise operator that *doesn't* modify its parameters into an (effectively) an assignment operator that writes to the screen, and which has side effects, is not great programming practice, as you can read in countless places on the web. Furthermore, the fact that `a << b;` is even a *statement* is itself not very clear why, because if anything, it should be `a <<= b;` (many languages like C# don't allow those kinds of "statements").

Comment: @Lambert: Given how rarely the average C++ programmer needs to deal with shifting bits, I think re-purposing them as `insertion` and `extraction` operators was a good move.  Qt went one step further and you can do `myList << newItem` to append an item to a list.

Comment: @Bill: Who says it's rare? How, for example, do you multiply a power of two? Do you recommend int x = (int)pow(i, 6)? And what if you don't even have floating-point available? Would you loop?

Also, the whole point is that the entire *semantics* of the << operator has changed: it's not supposed to modify its arguments, but it does. If anything, it should've been <<= instead.

Comment: Also, see the "Operator Overloading" section of the D language's Style Guide regarding the recommendation on which operators should be overloaded:
http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dstyle.html
As well as the Wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Criticisms

Comment: @Lambert: In my professional experience, I rarely need to use bit-shifting to multiply numbers.  (It doesn't happen often; when it does, `pow()` is more readable.  Or do you think it's good to have two different ways to do powers... one for 2, and one for everything else?  How do you do 3 to the 5th power with bit-shifting?)  I have never had floating point not available; you think not having it is common? ...

Comment: ... I know the semantics have changed, I'm suggesting that changing the semantics from "bit-shift" to "insertion/extraction" is a good thing.  Needing to manually shift bits falls in a similar category to needing to drop into assembler.  It's good that the functionality is there, but it's rare to need it.

Comment: @Bill: But my point is that it's *not* rare, as multiplying by powers of two certainly isn't (at least in a lot of the code I've seen). And just curious, do you think overloading << instead of <<= was a good choice?

Comment: @Bill: Also, another question: do you think `a + b;` should be a valid statement?

Comment: @Bill: Sorry for the 3 posts, just remembered the other part: I'm saying floating-point might not be common because if you're doing programming for some device other than an x86 CPU, it might not have it. So shifting is actually useful. Also, floating point is just plain slow, even if it's there... I'm not sure why you'd use it just for a bit shift.
Also, bit shifting can be used to separate out the dwords in a quadword, for example, so it's definitely used in some situations.

Comment: @Lambert: a) Most software (that I've seen) does not calculate powers of two in a tight loop.  Good thing too: how should I do pow(3, 5)?  b) `a + b` is a valid statement, so I'm not sure what your question is.  (It's even valid for `int`, although it has no visible effect.)  c) No problem!  I agree that bit-shifting can be used in some very specific circumstances.  However, it sounds like "<< meant bit-shifting 30 years ago, so that's what << should mean today, even though the average programmer never needs to bit-shift anymore!"

Comment: @Bill: I was asking if *you* think it *should* be a valid statement, which relates to my other question, "Do you think overloading << instead of <<= was a good choice?" Again, because << is not meant to modify its arguments, I think it's just like saying `2 + 3;` in your code -- it shouldn't be allowed because it's pointless, and if you overload your operators to actually make it do something, that's not good practice. IMHO, if they had made it be `cout <<= "hello";` instead, that would've been much better, since now we know that `cout` is modified. (This is a bit subjective, but not by much.)

Comment: @Lambert: Yes, I think repurposing `<<` as the insertion operator was a good choice.  That being said, I think it's natural for the insertion operator to modify what it's inserting into... a stream, a list, etc.  I also think it's natural for an extraction operator to modify whatever it's extracting from.  In my many years of programming, I've seen `<<` used *intentionally* to shift bits very infrequently, and I've seen and used `<<` as insertion quite a lot.  If it weren't for backward-compatability, they could have made a function called `bitshift` and had `<<` only mean insertion.

Comment: @Bill: But why not `<<=` instead?

Answer (score -1):

```
std::cout << greatest <<endl;
```